# How to define alias in OpenApi, eventually using it in Pojo

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

Let's assume I have this definition in my openapi.yml (this is just a madeup example to depict the issue I have):

```
components:
  schemas:
    Address:
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        zip:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        town:
          type: string
```

This will lead to the generation of code for the model that looks like this:

```
public class Address   {
  @JsonProperty("name")
  private String name = null;

  @JsonProperty("zip")
  private Long zip = null;

  @JsonProperty("town")
  private String town = null;
...
```

My issue is that I have to persist this Pojo in a database and there exists no table `Address` (let's assume it is called `Places` instead) and the column for the zipcode is called `zipcode` instead of `zip`.

So I would need *two* things:

- a way to tell OpenAPI about the aliases `Address=Places` and `zip=zipcode`.
- a way to make this information change the code created. For Hibernate for example this would mean to add `@Table(name="Places")` and `@Column(name="zipcode")` in the right places.

Important remark: I can not change the API, it is expected to stick to `Address` and `zip`.

Can this be done ? I checked the [specs](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/releases/tag/3.1.0) and both swagger-codegen and openapi-generator (I'ld prefer the latter) but found no sign that something like this is covered.
For openapi-generator I had a look at the [Mustache templates](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/e1d1ced117bf8dfec55f59815f744e84552df828/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/JavaSpring/pojo.mustache#L23) and as far as I can tell there is no code that refers any "alias information" that was defined in the yaml file.

Do I have to go the hard way and define an OpenAPI extension like [this](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/openapi-extensions/) or [this](https://apihandyman.io/writing-openapi-swagger-specification-tutorial-part-9-extending-the-openapi-specification/) plus [customize the templates](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/customization/#user-defined-templates) all by myself ?
The closest I could find is [this existing extension](https://rest.sh/#/openapi?id=name), that defines one type of alias. But this satisfies only the first part of my demand.

Comment: the only way to define alias in OpenAPI is through [$ref](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/)

Answer (score 0):

The use of openapi for the alias is simple, but bot architecture robust.

Introduce an AddressDto to handle the impedance mistmatch beteen public face (API) and internal model